# Where do I find strings for Error code in OpenCL (Nvidia )?

Tags: opencl, nvidia

Running a simple OpenCL Matrix Multiplication code on NVIDIA GPU, I get error code -30. I want to know what is the meaning of this code. I am sure the string corresponding to this code (int) must be stored somewhere. Can someone help me in interpreting this code? Once I know what this error mean I can debug my code easily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [CLEW](https://code.google.com/p/clew/) library:

```
const char* clewErrorString(cl_int error)
{
    static const char* strings[] =
    {
        // Error Codes
          "CL_SUCCESS"                                  //   0
        , "CL_DEVICE_NOT_FOUND"                         //  -1
        , "CL_DEVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE"                     //  -2
        , "CL_COMPILER_NOT_AVAILABLE"                   //  -3
        , "CL_MEM_OBJECT_ALLOCATION_FAILURE"            //  -4
        , "CL_OUT_OF_RESOURCES"                         //  -5
        , "CL_OUT_OF_HOST_MEMORY"                       //  -6
        , "CL_PROFILING_INFO_NOT_AVAILABLE"             //  -7
        , "CL_MEM_COPY_OVERLAP"                         //  -8
        , "CL_IMAGE_FORMAT_MISMATCH"                    //  -9
        , "CL_IMAGE_FORMAT_NOT_SUPPORTED"               //  -10
        , "CL_BUILD_PROGRAM_FAILURE"                    //  -11
        , "CL_MAP_FAILURE"                              //  -12

        , ""    //  -13
        , ""    //  -14
        , ""    //  -15
        , ""    //  -16
        , ""    //  -17
        , ""    //  -18
        , ""    //  -19

        , ""    //  -20
        , ""    //  -21
        , ""    //  -22
        , ""    //  -23
        , ""    //  -24
        , ""    //  -25
        , ""    //  -26
        , ""    //  -27
        , ""    //  -28
        , ""    //  -29

        , "CL_INVALID_VALUE"                            //  -30
        , "CL_INVALID_DEVICE_TYPE"                      //  -31
        , "CL_INVALID_PLATFORM"                         //  -32
        , "CL_INVALID_DEVICE"                           //  -33
        , "CL_INVALID_CONTEXT"                          //  -34
        , "CL_INVALID_QUEUE_PROPERTIES"                 //  -35
        , "CL_INVALID_COMMAND_QUEUE"                    //  -36
        , "CL_INVALID_HOST_PTR"                         //  -37
        , "CL_INVALID_MEM_OBJECT"                       //  -38
        , "CL_INVALID_IMAGE_FORMAT_DESCRIPTOR"          //  -39
        , "CL_INVALID_IMAGE_SIZE"                       //  -40
        , "CL_INVALID_SAMPLER"                          //  -41
        , "CL_INVALID_BINARY"                           //  -42
        , "CL_INVALID_BUILD_OPTIONS"                    //  -43
        , "CL_INVALID_PROGRAM"                          //  -44
        , "CL_INVALID_PROGRAM_EXECUTABLE"               //  -45
        , "CL_INVALID_KERNEL_NAME"                      //  -46
        , "CL_INVALID_KERNEL_DEFINITION"                //  -47
        , "CL_INVALID_KERNEL"                           //  -48
        , "CL_INVALID_ARG_INDEX"                        //  -49
        , "CL_INVALID_ARG_VALUE"                        //  -50
        , "CL_INVALID_ARG_SIZE"                         //  -51
        , "CL_INVALID_KERNEL_ARGS"                      //  -52
        , "CL_INVALID_WORK_DIMENSION"                   //  -53
        , "CL_INVALID_WORK_GROUP_SIZE"                  //  -54
        , "CL_INVALID_WORK_ITEM_SIZE"                   //  -55
        , "CL_INVALID_GLOBAL_OFFSET"                    //  -56
        , "CL_INVALID_EVENT_WAIT_LIST"                  //  -57
        , "CL_INVALID_EVENT"                            //  -58
        , "CL_INVALID_OPERATION"                        //  -59
        , "CL_INVALID_GL_OBJECT"                        //  -60
        , "CL_INVALID_BUFFER_SIZE"                      //  -61
        , "CL_INVALID_MIP_LEVEL"                        //  -62
        , "CL_INVALID_GLOBAL_WORK_SIZE"                 //  -63
        , "CL_UNKNOWN_ERROR_CODE"
    };

    if (error >= -63 && error <= 0)
         return strings[-error];
    else
         return strings[64];
}
```

There is an nVIDIA version and an AMD version of these. But I prefer to do it OpenSource and in a generic way.

Comment: Thanks for your quick help. By the way the error code to string mapping as shown above is a part of the standard? If so then NVIDIA must have also used it this way

Comment: I edited with a safer way. And yes, the codes are part of `cl.h` file.

Comment: That was precisely I was looking for

Comment: If you're using exceptions with the C++ wrapper, you can call `clewErrorString(exception.err())`

Answer (score 1):

If you're in C++, you can use the `opencl_error::to_string()` function in the [Boost.Compute](https://github.com/boostorg/compute) library. This will return a `std::string` with a human-readable description for a OpenCL error code.

For example:

```
std::cout << opencl_error::to_string(CL_INVALID_KERNEL_ARGS) << std::cout;
```

Will print:

```
"Invalid Kernel Arguments"
```

See the documentation here: http://boostorg.github.io/compute/boost/compute/opencl_error.html