# Convenient way to show OpenCL error codes?

Tags: opencl, error-code

As per title, is there a convenient way to show readable OpenCL error codes?

Being able to convert codes like '-1000' to a name would save a lot of time browsing through error codes.

Comment: I will refer you to a previous answer I did: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19134943/where-do-i-find-strings-for-error-code-in-opencl-nvidia/19135001#19135001

Comment: I guess duplicate of that question also ...

Comment: @DarkZeros Thanks. Seems like I missed a question after all.. Ugh.

Guess I was on the right track already, though.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

This is what I currently do. I believe the error list to be complete for OpenCL 1.2.

```
cl_int result = clSomeFunction();

if(result != CL_SUCCESS)
    std::cerr << getErrorString(result) << std::endl;
```

And getErrorString defined as follows:

```
const char *getErrorString(cl_int error)
{
switch(error){
    // run-time and JIT compiler errors
    case 0: return "CL_SUCCESS";
    case -1: return "CL_DEVICE_NOT_FOUND";
    case -2: return "CL_DEVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE";
    case -3: return "CL_COMPILER_NOT_AVAILABLE";
    case -4: return "CL_MEM_OBJECT_ALLOCATION_FAILURE";
    case -5: return "CL_OUT_OF_RESOURCES";
    case -6: return "CL_OUT_OF_HOST_MEMORY";
    case -7: return "CL_PROFILING_INFO_NOT_AVAILABLE";
    case -8: return "CL_MEM_COPY_OVERLAP";
    case -9: return "CL_IMAGE_FORMAT_MISMATCH";
    case -10: return "CL_IMAGE_FORMAT_NOT_SUPPORTED";
    case -11: return "CL_BUILD_PROGRAM_FAILURE";
    case -12: return "CL_MAP_FAILURE";
    case -13: return "CL_MISALIGNED_SUB_BUFFER_OFFSET";
    case -14: return "CL_EXEC_STATUS_ERROR_FOR_EVENTS_IN_WAIT_LIST";
    case -15: return "CL_COMPILE_PROGRAM_FAILURE";
    case -16: return "CL_LINKER_NOT_AVAILABLE";
    case -17: return "CL_LINK_PROGRAM_FAILURE";
    case -18: return "CL_DEVICE_PARTITION_FAILED";
    case -19: return "CL_KERNEL_ARG_INFO_NOT_AVAILABLE";

    // compile-time errors
    case -30: return "CL_INVALID_VALUE";
    case -31: return "CL_INVALID_DEVICE_TYPE";
    case -32: return "CL_INVALID_PLATFORM";
    case -33: return "CL_INVALID_DEVICE";
    case -34: return "CL_INVALID_CONTEXT";
    case -35: return "CL_INVALID_QUEUE_PROPERTIES";
    case -36: return "CL_INVALID_COMMAND_QUEUE";
    case -37: return "CL_INVALID_HOST_PTR";
    case -38: return "CL_INVALID_MEM_OBJECT";
    case -39: return "CL_INVALID_IMAGE_FORMAT_DESCRIPTOR";
    case -40: return "CL_INVALID_IMAGE_SIZE";
    case -41: return "CL_INVALID_SAMPLER";
    case -42: return "CL_INVALID_BINARY";
    case -43: return "CL_INVALID_BUILD_OPTIONS";
    case -44: return "CL_INVALID_PROGRAM";
    case -45: return "CL_INVALID_PROGRAM_EXECUTABLE";
    case -46: return "CL_INVALID_KERNEL_NAME";
    case -47: return "CL_INVALID_KERNEL_DEFINITION";
    case -48: return "CL_INVALID_KERNEL";
    case -49: return "CL_INVALID_ARG_INDEX";
    case -50: return "CL_INVALID_ARG_VALUE";
    case -51: return "CL_INVALID_ARG_SIZE";
    case -52: return "CL_INVALID_KERNEL_ARGS";
    case -53: return "CL_INVALID_WORK_DIMENSION";
    case -54: return "CL_INVALID_WORK_GROUP_SIZE";
    case -55: return "CL_INVALID_WORK_ITEM_SIZE";
    case -56: return "CL_INVALID_GLOBAL_OFFSET";
    case -57: return "CL_INVALID_EVENT_WAIT_LIST";
    case -58: return "CL_INVALID_EVENT";
    case -59: return "CL_INVALID_OPERATION";
    case -60: return "CL_INVALID_GL_OBJECT";
    case -61: return "CL_INVALID_BUFFER_SIZE";
    case -62: return "CL_INVALID_MIP_LEVEL";
    case -63: return "CL_INVALID_GLOBAL_WORK_SIZE";
    case -64: return "CL_INVALID_PROPERTY";
    case -65: return "CL_INVALID_IMAGE_DESCRIPTOR";
    case -66: return "CL_INVALID_COMPILER_OPTIONS";
    case -67: return "CL_INVALID_LINKER_OPTIONS";
    case -68: return "CL_INVALID_DEVICE_PARTITION_COUNT";

    // extension errors
    case -1000: return "CL_INVALID_GL_SHAREGROUP_REFERENCE_KHR";
    case -1001: return "CL_PLATFORM_NOT_FOUND_KHR";
    case -1002: return "CL_INVALID_D3D10_DEVICE_KHR";
    case -1003: return "CL_INVALID_D3D10_RESOURCE_KHR";
    case -1004: return "CL_D3D10_RESOURCE_ALREADY_ACQUIRED_KHR";
    case -1005: return "CL_D3D10_RESOURCE_NOT_ACQUIRED_KHR";
    default: return "Unknown OpenCL error";
    }
}
```

Comment: @chippies Thanks, seems like I forgot to add that one. That would be "CL_PLATFORM_NOT_FOUND_KHR". Updated in the answer.

Comment: Thanks for punching this in ... one would hope the OpenCL lib(s) came with a cl::strerror() or the likes included. Sheesh.

Comment: If you're using exceptions with the C++ wrapper, you can call `getErrorString(exception.err())`

Comment: I got error code -9999(because I used the unsupported instructions).

Answer (score 8):

For anyone who need different version of OpenCL error code to string, [here](https://github.com/WanghongLin/miscellaneous/blob/master/tools/clext.py) is a small script can help you.

```
$ ./clext.py /directory/to/opencl/headers
```

For example, to create error code to string help function for OpenCL 2.2, you can run

```
$ ./clext.py ~/Developments/OpenCL-Headers/opencl22/CL
```

will create a file `clext.h` in your current directory.

Then you can include this file in your project, and use the call `const char* clGetErrorString(int errorCode)` to get error string from error code.

Here is the content of the generated file `clext.h` for OpenCL 2.2.

```
// auto generated from ./clext.py
#ifndef __CL_EXT__
#define __CL_EXT__


#include <stdio.h>


/*
 * Given a cl code and return a string represenation
 */
const char* clGetErrorString(int errorCode) {
    switch (errorCode) {
        case 0: return "CL_SUCCESS";
        case -1: return "CL_DEVICE_NOT_FOUND";
        case -2: return "CL_DEVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE";
        case -3: return "CL_COMPILER_NOT_AVAILABLE";
        case -4: return "CL_MEM_OBJECT_ALLOCATION_FAILURE";
        case -5: return "CL_OUT_OF_RESOURCES";
        case -6: return "CL_OUT_OF_HOST_MEMORY";
        case -7: return "CL_PROFILING_INFO_NOT_AVAILABLE";
        case -8: return "CL_MEM_COPY_OVERLAP";
        case -9: return "CL_IMAGE_FORMAT_MISMATCH";
        case -10: return "CL_IMAGE_FORMAT_NOT_SUPPORTED";
        case -12: return "CL_MAP_FAILURE";
        case -13: return "CL_MISALIGNED_SUB_BUFFER_OFFSET";
        case -14: return "CL_EXEC_STATUS_ERROR_FOR_EVENTS_IN_WAIT_LIST";
        case -15: return "CL_COMPILE_PROGRAM_FAILURE";
        case -16: return "CL_LINKER_NOT_AVAILABLE";
        case -17: return "CL_LINK_PROGRAM_FAILURE";
        case -18: return "CL_DEVICE_PARTITION_FAILED";
        case -19: return "CL_KERNEL_ARG_INFO_NOT_AVAILABLE";
        case -30: return "CL_INVALID_VALUE";
        case -31: return "CL_INVALID_DEVICE_TYPE";
        case -32: return "CL_INVALID_PLATFORM";
        case -33: return "CL_INVALID_DEVICE";
        case -34: return "CL_INVALID_CONTEXT";
        case -35: return "CL_INVALID_QUEUE_PROPERTIES";
        case -36: return "CL_INVALID_COMMAND_QUEUE";
        case -37: return "CL_INVALID_HOST_PTR";
        case -38: return "CL_INVALID_MEM_OBJECT";
        case -39: return "CL_INVALID_IMAGE_FORMAT_DESCRIPTOR";
        case -40: return "CL_INVALID_IMAGE_SIZE";
        case -41: return "CL_INVALID_SAMPLER";
        case -42: return "CL_INVALID_BINARY";
        case -43: return "CL_INVALID_BUILD_OPTIONS";
        case -44: return "CL_INVALID_PROGRAM";
        case -45: return "CL_INVALID_PROGRAM_EXECUTABLE";
        case -46: return "CL_INVALID_KERNEL_NAME";
        case -47: return "CL_INVALID_KERNEL_DEFINITION";
        case -48: return "CL_INVALID_KERNEL";
        case -49: return "CL_INVALID_ARG_INDEX";
        case -50: return "CL_INVALID_ARG_VALUE";
        case -51: return "CL_INVALID_ARG_SIZE";
        case -52: return "CL_INVALID_KERNEL_ARGS";
        case -53: return "CL_INVALID_WORK_DIMENSION";
        case -54: return "CL_INVALID_WORK_GROUP_SIZE";
        case -55: return "CL_INVALID_WORK_ITEM_SIZE";
        case -56: return "CL_INVALID_GLOBAL_OFFSET";
        case -57: return "CL_INVALID_EVENT_WAIT_LIST";
        case -58: return "CL_INVALID_EVENT";
        case -59: return "CL_INVALID_OPERATION";
        case -60: return "CL_INVALID_GL_OBJECT";
        case -61: return "CL_INVALID_BUFFER_SIZE";
        case -62: return "CL_INVALID_MIP_LEVEL";
        case -63: return "CL_INVALID_GLOBAL_WORK_SIZE";
        case -64: return "CL_INVALID_PROPERTY";
        case -65: return "CL_INVALID_IMAGE_DESCRIPTOR";
        case -66: return "CL_INVALID_COMPILER_OPTIONS";
        case -67: return "CL_INVALID_LINKER_OPTIONS";
        case -68: return "CL_INVALID_DEVICE_PARTITION_COUNT";
        case -69: return "CL_INVALID_PIPE_SIZE";
        case -70: return "CL_INVALID_DEVICE_QUEUE";
        case -71: return "CL_INVALID_SPEC_ID";
        case -72: return "CL_MAX_SIZE_RESTRICTION_EXCEEDED";
        case -1002: return "CL_INVALID_D3D10_DEVICE_KHR";
        case -1003: return "CL_INVALID_D3D10_RESOURCE_KHR";
        case -1004: return "CL_D3D10_RESOURCE_ALREADY_ACQUIRED_KHR";
        case -1005: return "CL_D3D10_RESOURCE_NOT_ACQUIRED_KHR";
        case -1006: return "CL_INVALID_D3D11_DEVICE_KHR";
        case -1007: return "CL_INVALID_D3D11_RESOURCE_KHR";
        case -1008: return "CL_D3D11_RESOURCE_ALREADY_ACQUIRED_KHR";
        case -1009: return "CL_D3D11_RESOURCE_NOT_ACQUIRED_KHR";
        case -1010: return "CL_INVALID_DX9_MEDIA_ADAPTER_KHR";
        case -1011: return "CL_INVALID_DX9_MEDIA_SURFACE_KHR";
        case -1012: return "CL_DX9_MEDIA_SURFACE_ALREADY_ACQUIRED_KHR";
        case -1013: return "CL_DX9_MEDIA_SURFACE_NOT_ACQUIRED_KHR";
        case -1093: return "CL_INVALID_EGL_OBJECT_KHR";
        case -1092: return "CL_EGL_RESOURCE_NOT_ACQUIRED_KHR";
        case -1001: return "CL_PLATFORM_NOT_FOUND_KHR";
        case -1057: return "CL_DEVICE_PARTITION_FAILED_EXT";
        case -1058: return "CL_INVALID_PARTITION_COUNT_EXT";
        case -1059: return "CL_INVALID_PARTITION_NAME_EXT";
        case -1094: return "CL_INVALID_ACCELERATOR_INTEL";
        case -1095: return "CL_INVALID_ACCELERATOR_TYPE_INTEL";
        case -1096: return "CL_INVALID_ACCELERATOR_DESCRIPTOR_INTEL";
        case -1097: return "CL_ACCELERATOR_TYPE_NOT_SUPPORTED_INTEL";
        case -1000: return "CL_INVALID_GL_SHAREGROUP_REFERENCE_KHR";
        case -1098: return "CL_INVALID_VA_API_MEDIA_ADAPTER_INTEL";
        case -1099: return "CL_INVALID_VA_API_MEDIA_SURFACE_INTEL";
        case -1100: return "CL_VA_API_MEDIA_SURFACE_ALREADY_ACQUIRED_INTEL";
        case -1101: return "CL_VA_API_MEDIA_SURFACE_NOT_ACQUIRED_INTEL";
        default: return "CL_UNKNOWN_ERROR";
    }
}

/*
 * check cl error, if not CL_SUCCESS, print to stderr
 */
int clCheckError(int errorCode) {
    if (errorCode != 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", clGetErrorString(errorCode));
    }
    return errorCode;
}

#endif /* __CL_EXT__*/
```

Answer (score 6):

If you don't like the hard-coded error codes in the other answers, here is what I do in C:

```
#define CaseReturnString(x) case x: return #x;

const char *opencl_errstr(cl_int err)
{
    switch (err)
    {
        CaseReturnString(CL_SUCCESS                        )                                  
        CaseReturnString(CL_DEVICE_NOT_FOUND               )
        CaseReturnString(CL_DEVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE           )
        CaseReturnString(CL_COMPILER_NOT_AVAILABLE         ) 
        CaseReturnString(CL_MEM_OBJECT_ALLOCATION_FAILURE  )
        CaseReturnString(CL_OUT_OF_RESOURCES               )
        CaseReturnString(CL_OUT_OF_HOST_MEMORY             )
        CaseReturnString(CL_PROFILING_INFO_NOT_AVAILABLE   )
        CaseReturnString(CL_MEM_COPY_OVERLAP               )
        CaseReturnString(CL_IMAGE_FORMAT_MISMATCH          )
        CaseReturnString(CL_IMAGE_FORMAT_NOT_SUPPORTED     )
        CaseReturnString(CL_BUILD_PROGRAM_FAILURE          )
        CaseReturnString(CL_MAP_FAILURE                    )
        CaseReturnString(CL_MISALIGNED_SUB_BUFFER_OFFSET   )
        CaseReturnString(CL_COMPILE_PROGRAM_FAILURE        )
        CaseReturnString(CL_LINKER_NOT_AVAILABLE           )
        CaseReturnString(CL_LINK_PROGRAM_FAILURE           )
        CaseReturnString(CL_DEVICE_PARTITION_FAILED        )
        CaseReturnString(CL_KERNEL_ARG_INFO_NOT_AVAILABLE  )
        CaseReturnString(CL_INVALID_VALUE                  )
        CaseReturnString(CL_INVALID_DEVICE_TYPE            )
        CaseReturnString(CL_INVALID_PLATFORM               )
        CaseReturnString(CL_INVALID_DEVICE                 )
        CaseReturnString(CL_INVALID_CONTEXT                )
        CaseReturnString(CL_INVALID_QUEUE_PROPERTIES       )
        CaseReturnString(CL_INVALID_COMMAND_QUEUE          )
        CaseReturnString(CL_INVALID_HOST_PTR               )
        CaseReturnString(CL_INVALID_MEM_OBJECT             )
        CaseReturnString(CL_INVALID_IMAGE_FORMAT_DESCRIPTOR)
        CaseReturnString(CL_INVALID_IMAGE_SIZE             )
        CaseReturnString(CL_INVALID_SAMPLER                )
        CaseReturnString(CL_INVALID_BINARY                 )
        CaseReturnString(CL_INVALID_BUILD_OPTIONS          )
        CaseReturnString(CL_INVALID_PROGRAM                )
        CaseReturnString(CL_INVALID_PROGRAM_EXECUTABLE     )
        CaseReturnString(CL_INVALID_KERNEL_NAME            )
        CaseReturnString(CL_INVALID_KERNEL_DEFINITION      )
        CaseReturnString(CL_INVALID_KERNEL                 )
        CaseReturnString(CL_INVALID_ARG_INDEX              )
        CaseReturnString(CL_INVALID_ARG_VALUE              )
        CaseReturnString(CL_INVALID_ARG_SIZE               )
        CaseReturnString(CL_INVALID_KERNEL_ARGS            )
        CaseReturnString(CL_INVALID_WORK_DIMENSION         )
        CaseReturnString(CL_INVALID_WORK_GROUP_SIZE        )
        CaseReturnString(CL_INVALID_WORK_ITEM_SIZE         )
        CaseReturnString(CL_INVALID_GLOBAL_OFFSET          )
        CaseReturnString(CL_INVALID_EVENT_WAIT_LIST        )
        CaseReturnString(CL_INVALID_EVENT                  )
        CaseReturnString(CL_INVALID_OPERATION              )
        CaseReturnString(CL_INVALID_GL_OBJECT              )
        CaseReturnString(CL_INVALID_BUFFER_SIZE            )
        CaseReturnString(CL_INVALID_MIP_LEVEL              )
        CaseReturnString(CL_INVALID_GLOBAL_WORK_SIZE       )
        CaseReturnString(CL_INVALID_PROPERTY               )
        CaseReturnString(CL_INVALID_IMAGE_DESCRIPTOR       )
        CaseReturnString(CL_INVALID_COMPILER_OPTIONS       )
        CaseReturnString(CL_INVALID_LINKER_OPTIONS         )
        CaseReturnString(CL_INVALID_DEVICE_PARTITION_COUNT )
        default: return "Unknown OpenCL error code";
    }
}
```