# CUDA fails to initialise when address sanitizer is enabled

Tags: c++, cuda

I have the following CMake project:

File: CMakeLists.txt

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0)
project(SampleProgram LANGUAGES CXX CUDA)

find_package(CUDA REQUIRED)

set(CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS ${CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS} -G)

cuda_add_executable(sampleProgram main.cpp)
target_compile_options(sampleProgram PUBLIC -Wall -Wextra -fsanitize=address,undefined)
target_link_libraries(sampleProgram stdc++fs -fsanitize=address,undefined)

set_property(TARGET sampleProgram PROPERTY CUDA_ARCHITECTURES 52 60 61 70 75 86)
```

File: main.cpp:

```
#include "cuda_runtime.h"
#include "Common/helper_cuda.h"
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, const char** argv) {
    int deviceCount;
    checkCudaErrors(cudaGetDeviceCount(&deviceCount));
    std::cout << "Detected " << deviceCount << " devices" << std::endl;
}
```

The checkCudaErrors() macro is used from the NVidia CUDA samples project.

When I compile and run this project I get:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::runtime_error'
  what():  CUDA error at /home/X/Documents/main.cpp:7 code=2(cudaErrorMemoryAllocation) "cudaGetDeviceCount(&deviceCount)"
Aborted (core dumped)
```

When I remove the "-fsanitize=address,undefined" from both the compile and link options, the program works without any errors and prints out the expected number of GPUs.

Relevant specs:

- OS: Ubuntu 22.04.2
- CUDA version: 11.6 (also tried 12.0 + driver 525 previously, same issue)
- Driver version: 510.108.03
- nvidia-smi is working without issues
- Compiler: GNU 11.3.0, also tried 12.1.0 with the same issue.
- System is up-to-date according to apt.

Comment: Combining asan and CUDA has been an issue for years. There is a workaround, see [asan: problem calling NVIDIA CUDA libraries #629](https://github.com/google/sanitizers/issues/629) in the sanitizers repository.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55750700/opencl-usable-when-compiling-host-application-with-address-sanitizer