# C++ OpenCL Abstraction Not giving desired result

Tags: c++, gpu, opencl

I tried to do an basic abstraction for OpenCL Here it is:

OpenCLBuffer:
Header:

```
class OpenCLBuffer {    
    void* GetNativeID() { return obj; }

    cl_mem obj;
    cl_command_queue commandQueue;
    cl_context context;
    cl_int ret;
    int type;
    int maxSize;
    int currSize;
};
```

Impl:

```
OpenCLBuffer::OpenCLBuffer(cl_context cont, cl_command_queue queue, cl_int t, unsigned int size)
{
    context = cont;
    commandQueue = queue;
    maxSize = size;
    type = t;
    obj = clCreateBuffer(context, t, size, NULL, &ret);
}

OpenCLBuffer::~OpenCLBuffer()
{
    ret = clReleaseMemObject(obj);
}

void OpenCLBuffer::SetData(int size, void* data, int offset)
{
    currSize = size;
    ret = clEnqueueWriteBuffer(commandQueue, obj, CL_TRUE, offset, size, data, 0, NULL,  NULL);
}

void OpenCLBuffer::GetData(void* data, int size)
{
    if (size == -1)
        size = currSize;
    ret = clEnqueueReadBuffer(commandQueue, obj, CL_TRUE, 0, size, data, 0, NULL, NULL);
}
```

OpenClContext:
Header:

```
class OpenCLContext {
// I removed the fuc definations from question as they are already in the Impl part
    cl_platform_id plarformId;
    cl_device_id deviceId;
    cl_context context;
    cl_uint numDevices;
    cl_uint numPlatforms;
    cl_command_queue commandQueue;  
    cl_int ret;
    char name[1024];
};
```

ImPl:

```
static void _stdcall OpenCLErrorFunc(const char* errinfo, const void* private_info, size_t cb, void* user_data){
    std::cout << "OpenCL (" << user_data << ") Error : \n" << errinfo << "\n";
}

OpenCLContext::OpenCLContext(std::string n)
{
    ret = clGetPlatformIDs(1, &plarformId, &numPlatforms);
    ret = clGetDeviceIDs(plarformId, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_DEFAULT, 1, &deviceId, &numDevices);
    context = clCreateContext(NULL, 1, &deviceId, OpenCLErrorFunc, name, &ret);
    commandQueue = clCreateCommandQueue(context, deviceId, 0, &ret);

    memcpy_s(name, 1024, n.data(), std::min(1024, (int)n.size()));
}

OpenCLContext::~OpenCLContext()
{
    for (std::pair<std::string, char*> data : sources) {
        if (data.second)
            delete data.second;
    }

    ret = clFlush(commandQueue);
    ret = clReleaseCommandQueue(commandQueue);
    ret = clReleaseContext(context);
}

OpenCLBuffer* OpenCLContext::CreateBuffer(void* data, int size, int type)
{
    OpenCLBuffer* buffer = new OpenCLBuffer(context, commandQueue, type, size);
    buffer->SetData(size, data);
    return buffer;
}

OpenCLBuffer* OpenCLContext::CreateBuffer(int size, int type)
{
    OpenCLBuffer* buffer = new OpenCLBuffer(context, commandQueue, type, size);
    return buffer;
}

void OpenCLContext::AddProgram(std::string name, std::string source)
{
    char* sc = new char[source.size()];
    memcpy_s(sc, source.size(), source.data(), source.size());
    sources[name] = sc;
    int sourceSize = source.size();
    programs[name] = clCreateProgramWithSource(context, 1, (const char**)&sc, (const size_t*)&sourceSize, &ret);
    ret = clBuildProgram(programs[name], 1, &deviceId, NULL, NULL, NULL);
}

void OpenCLContext::MakeKernel(std::string programName, std::string kernelName)
{
    kernels[kernelName] = clCreateKernel(programs[programName], kernelName.c_str(), &ret);
}

void OpenCLContext::SetKernelArg(std::string kernelName, int num, int size, void* arg)
{
    ret = clSetKernelArg(kernels[kernelName], num, size, arg);
}

void OpenCLContext::ReleaseKernerl(std::string kernelName)
{
    ret = clFlush(commandQueue);
    ret = clReleaseKernel(kernels[kernelName]);
}

void OpenCLContext::ReleaseProgram(std::string programName)
{
    ret = clFlush(commandQueue);
    ret = clReleaseProgram(programs[programName]);
}

void OpenCLContext::Dispatch(std::string kernelName, int globalItemSize, int localItemSize)
{
    ret = clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(commandQueue, kernels[kernelName], 1, NULL, (const size_t*)&globalItemSize, (const size_t*)&localItemSize, 0, NULL, NULL);
}
```

Driver Code:

```
std::string shadersrc = R"(
__kernel void vector_add(__global const int *A, __global const int *B, __global int *C) {
 
    // Get the index of the current element to be processed
    int i = get_global_id(0);
 
    // Do the operation
    C[i] = A[i] + B[i];
}
)";
const int LIST_SIZE = 1024;
    int* A = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * LIST_SIZE);
    int* B = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * LIST_SIZE);
    for (int i = 0; i < LIST_SIZE; i++) {
        A[i] = i;
        B[i] = LIST_SIZE - i;
    }
    context = new OpenCLContext("Vector Adder");
    a = context->CreateBuffer(LIST_SIZE * sizeof(int), CL_MEM_READ_ONLY);
    b = context->CreateBuffer(LIST_SIZE * sizeof(int), CL_MEM_READ_ONLY);
    c = context->CreateBuffer(LIST_SIZE * sizeof(int), CL_MEM_WRITE_ONLY);

    a->SetData(LIST_SIZE * sizeof(int), A);
    b->SetData(LIST_SIZE * sizeof(int), B);

    context->AddProgram("VectorAdderSrc", shadersrc);
    context->MakeKernel("VectorAdderSrc", "vector_add");

    context->SetKernelArg("vector_add", 0, sizeof(cl_mem), a->GetNativeID());
    context->SetKernelArg("vector_add", 1, sizeof(cl_mem), b->GetNativeID());
    context->SetKernelArg("vector_add", 2, sizeof(cl_mem), c->GetNativeID());

    context->Dispatch("vector_add", LIST_SIZE, 64);
 
    int* C = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * LIST_SIZE);
    memset(C, 0, sizeof(int) * LIST_SIZE);
    c->GetData(c, sizeof(int) * LIST_SIZE);

    for (int i = 0; i < LIST_SIZE; i++)
        printf("%d + %d = %d\n", A[i], B[i], C[i]);
```

Sometimes i am getting Read Access Violation and sometimes:

```
0 + 1024 = 0
1 + 1023 = 0
2 + 1022 = 0
3 + 1021 = 0
...
```

Then crash.

Could you please help me find the problems?

Answer (score 1):

First, few general tips to make debugging easier:

1. Always check return values. Every OpenCL API reports the errors via return value or a reference parameter.
2. At the first occurrence of an error you should stop the rest of the program as it will most likely not work. Throwing exceptions are a good strategy.
3. Specifically for OpenCL, the error codes are defined in the main header cl.h, you can find an code->string mapping routine here:[Convenient way to show OpenCL error codes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24326432/convenient-way-to-show-opencl-error-codes)

Regarding your code, the first error came from your function AddProgram. The function clCreateProgramWithSource returns CL_OUT_OF_HOST_MEMORY. Your decision to cast sourceSize from int* to size_t* is problematic since they are not the same size, and the API reads a corrupted 64-bit value.

Here is a better implementation:

```
void AddProgram(std::string name, std::string source)
{
    const char* sc = source.c_str();
    size_t sourceSize[1] = {source.size()};
    programs[name] = clCreateProgramWithSource(context, 1, &sc, sourceSize, &ret);
    ret = clBuildProgram(programs[name], 1, &deviceId, NULL, NULL, NULL);
}
```

There is no need to keep the source code in memory after it was compiled, but if you really want to, I suggest managing std::string objects because they save the hustle of managing memory.

The next problem is that clEnqueueNDRangeKernel returns CL_INVALID_WORK_GROUP_SIZE. Here you can find the int* to size_t* cast problem again, which passes bad arguments to the function.

Finally, your call to SetKernelArg returns CL_INVALID_MEM_OBJECT, and this is because the last argument, in case of OpenCL buffers, expected to be a pointer pointer to a cl_mem object (in your case - address of cl_mem that is returned by GetNativeID()).

Finally, there is a typo in the line `c->GetData(c, sizeof(int) * LIST_SIZE);` as it should be `c->GetData(C, sizeof(int) * LIST_SIZE);`

That should make it work. Please pay attention to the tips above, and avoid C casts in favor of C++ casts.